# Error while trying to create a new Multi-Device Hybrid App Project with spaces in project path

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Every time that I try to create a new Multi-Device Hybrid App Project  with Visual Studio it throws the following error:

> The path you have entered contains a space. Please select a location without a space when creating a mMulti-device Hybrid App.

[image: visual studio the path you have entered contains a space. Please select a location without a space when creating a mMulti-device Hybrid App]

I tried to report this to MS, but apparently StackOverflow is their MS/developers Channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround, every time I was trying to create a project was in the default **location** for Visual Studio **Projects folder**, I changed the location for a custom folder under "my documents" and it let me create a project.

**EDIT**
From the [known issues page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722404.aspx) as @Priyank said: "Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 platforms will error when you build or debug if a space is anywhere in your path. Windows 8 does not pick up some config.xml attributes due to a Cordova platform issue."

Just remove any "blank space" from your path, change the location of your project to a space-less path.

"[Its a Cordova platform issue (issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6256)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6256)" --  Priyank

**EDIT 2**
I wrote an step-by-step tutorial to get started with Apache Cordova apps with Visual Studio
[Hands on Apache Cordova with Visual Studio](http://robalarcon.com/2014/06/18/hands-on-the-apache-cordova-plugin-multi-device-hybrid-apps-integrated-in-visual-studio-2013-update-2/)

[image]

Comment: Comment is inaccurate. This issue is mentioned as the first issue on the Known Issues page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dn722404.aspx) under Apache Ripple section. Its a Cordova platform issue (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6256)

Comment: "Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 platforms will error when you build or debug if a space is anywhere in your path. Windows 8 does not pick up some config.xml attributes due to a Cordova platform issue." mmm... I guess I was tired, you're right. Somehow yesterday I thought that the word "space" meant something different, besides of being a space character (literally).

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem so i made new directory path which did not contain any directory or sub-directory name that contain spaces..
For Example : 
instead of "C:\Users\rob\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects" you should use "C:\Users\rob\Documents\VisualStudio2013\Projects" where no spaces occur in any dir names..

It must work else no other solution..